# How do you load any partial in a single modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out to load a sign UP partial and a sign IN partial in the same bootstrap  modal code in an effort to keep it dry.

How is that possible with my current situation?

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", :sign_in, id: "signin",  "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#sign-in" %>
```

modal partial

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign In</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render "sessions/new" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

New session partial

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

        <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would render both partials and use javascript to show/hide the correct ones. Make sure in your signup partial you use the class `signup` in the outermost element and render that within render that right below your signin partial

```
<%= link_to "Sign in", :sign_in, id: "signin",  "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#sign-in" %>

<%= link_to "Sign in", :sign_in, id: "signup",  "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#sign-in" %>

<div class="row signin">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

        <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#signin").click(function() {
    $(".modal .signup").hide();
    $(".modal .signin").show();
  });

  $("#signup").click(function() {
    $(".modal .signin").hide();
    $(".modal .signup").show();
  });
});
```

### Another way

Another way to do it would be to use ajax to load your partial into the body of the modal. You'd want a controller action for it that simply renders a partial and has `layout false` so you don't get excess layout elements passed with it.

If you don't have a lot, you don't need to make it a new controller, but I just did that here

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#signup").click(function() {
    setModal("modals/signup");
  });

  $("#signin").click(function() {
    setModal("modals/signin");
  });
});

// Doesn't have to be in a function, but it's better to keep it dry.
// Could also add more configuration (like the selector it uses)
function setModal(url) {
  $.get(url, function(data) {
    $("#myModal .modal-body").html(data);
  });
 }
```

### Controller

```
class ModalsController < ApplicationController
  def signin
    render partial: "sessions/new", layout: false
  end

  def signup
    render partial: "registrations/new", layout: false
  end
end
```

### Routes

```
get "modals/signin", to: "modals#signin"
get "modals/signup", to: "modals#signup"
```

Comment: Actually, I would be interested in seeing that. Thanks!